# Gnome system monitor alternative

Tags: gnome, system-monitor

I used to love gnome system monitor, ans used it often. But now, they changed the look to make it fit to Gnome 3 style, and it just doesn't fit to my desktop any more. So I actually have two questions:

1. Is it OK to just run an old version of the program, or are there reasons to have the newest version?
2. Is there something like gnome-system-monitor, e.g. similar GUI, and gtk based?

EDIT: Here is a screenshot.
[image: screenshot]

I like the way it has tabs to show different content. The leftmost one shows system information, the next one lists the processes, the visible one shows resources, and the last one gives some information about the file systems, e.g. free space.

For the replacement, I don't care so much about the system and file system information, but the processes and resources tabs are important.

Comment: Please do describe the interface for thoose of us who don't know the gnome system monitor (a screenshot maybe?) Also tell us what you liked from it, why it fitted your needs.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer done.

Comment: Great, just another Question: Are you stuck on Gnome3 or would using MATE (the Gnome 2 fork) be fine with you? There your "old" monitor would work

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer I looked at that, but I'm really happy with Cinnamon at the moment. I also saw mate-system-monitor on the AUR (I use Arch), but it had tons of MATE dependencies (like the icon theme!), so I didn't install it. Do you know what Ubuntu uses? It seems to be gnome-system-monitor, but with the "old" interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For people running Arch like me, there is a package called gnome-system-monitor-old in the AUR. I don't know about Ubuntu or Fedora of other distros.

As the name suggests, it is simply an old-style gnome system monitor, based on gtk2 I think. A screenshot would be useless, of course, as it looks just like the old system monitor in my question.